# Error when carrying out exp lincom function on multiple imputed data in R

Tags: r, regression, imputation, r-mice, exponentiation

I am trying to use (exp(lincom) to calculate the percentage change of GEE model outputs using (exp(lincom(data, variable)))-1.
However, I had to account for missing data using MICE, thus changing the final data object to mipo (after pooling).

I am trying to calculate the percentage change of GEE model estimate outputs using exp(lincom(gee_imputed_data, variable)))-1, and the following error occurs; Error in UseMethod("vcov") :
no applicable method for 'vcov' applied to an object of class "c('mira', 'matrix')" or  no applicable method for 'vcov' applied to an object of class "c('mipo', 'data.frame'

Is there a way to carry this out on data following multiple imputation? Do I need to convert the data output ?

> I carried out multiple imputation to produce imputed_data

> I then carry out GEE on the imputed data to produce gee_imputed_data

```
gee_imputed_data<-with( imputed_data , geeglm( variable ~
          v1+
          v2+
          v3+             
  id = id,
  family = gaussian(),
  waves = t,
   corstr = "ar1"             
) )
```

following this I would like to use (exp(lincom(x, c("v1")))-1) to calculate the percentage change for variables in the model- however this does not work on the imputed data set gee_imputed_data or the pooled data

```
(exp(lincom(gee_imputed_data, c("v1")))-1)* 100 #   
Error in UseMethod("vcov") : 
  no applicable method for 'vcov' applied to an object of class "c('mira', 'matrix')"
```

```
pool.data<-pool(gee_imputed_data)
(exp(lincom(pool.data, c("v1")))-1)* 100 
Error in UseMethod("vcov") : 
  no applicable method for 'vcov' applied to an object of class "c('mipo', 'data.frame')"
```

The above equation has been used as successful approach on regular data following gee, however the type of data following MICE multiple imputations has posed a challenge. If anyone could please advise how I can continue with this method on this data object gee_imputed_data I would be very appreciative

I will add a reproducible example below

```
my_data <- data.frame(
  la_code = rep("E06000001", 12),
  year = 1:12,
  pop_est = c(90000, 92000, 88000, 91000, 94000, 95000, 87000, 93000, 89000, 92000, 91000, 92000),  # Manually entered values for pop_est
  impute_variable = c(50, 70, 80, 100, 60, 90, 40, 70, 90, 60, 50, 80)  
)

# Define imputation methods
imputation_methods <- c(
  "",              
  "",             
  "",              
  "pmm"            # impute_variable


# Multiple Imputation
imp_2 <- mice(my_data, m = 20, meth = imputation_methods,
              maxit = 5, pri = FALSE, seed = 6466)

# Analyze Imputed Data
gee_imp <- with(imp_2, geeglm(impute_variable ~
               year +
               offset(log(pop_est)),
               id = la_code,
               family = gaussian(link = "log"),
               waves = year,
               corstr = "ar1"))

# Summary of One Imputation
summary(gee_imp$analyses[[1]])

# Pool Imputations
pool.fit <- pool(gee_imp)

# Calculate an expression from pooled results
result <- (exp(lincom(pool.fit, c("year"))) - 1) * 100
```

Comment: You have 1 extra bracket on the right side here: exp(lincom(pool.fit, c("v1")))-1)* 100  Also, if you are hoping for a more detailed answer and in case this doesn't work, please post a reproducible example.

Comment: Thank you for your response, the bracket was an error on - I have now fixed it so it should match the code. I am new to this so hopefully my reproducible example works.